Как запустить команду ffmpeg в фоне и корректно остановить процесс?
Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы при запуске определенной программы на ПК запустить запись экрана через ffmpeg (все остальные инструменты не подходят). После завершения программы мне нужно корректно остановить процесс записи так чтобы запись сохранилась в файл.

Это можно сделать либо через ctrl+c в терминале где выполняется скрипт. Но возникает вопрос, как программно послать такую остановку в работающий терминал.

Это можно сделать через закрытие терминала на "крестик" - но как тогда программно найти нужный мне терминал где запущен скрипт.


При завершении процесса ffmpeg через его принудительную остановку запись видео сохраняется некорректно и сам видеофайл не читается
Команда в power shell для записи экрана (пробовал указывать разные флаги)
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -r 5 -i desktop -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf format=gray C:\py\output1.mp4

